# Best practice: A compose B, DerivedA compose DerivedB

Tags: c++, coding-style

- struct `B` holds data.
- struct `DerivedB`: `B` adds some specific data to `B`.
- class `A` holds a reference to an object of type `B`.
- class `DerivedA` holds a reference to an object of type `DerivedB`.

Is it inherently a bad design?

If not, what is the **best way of achieving that**?

```
class A
{
public:
    A() :m_b(std::make_unique<B>(B())) {}
    B& getB() { return *m_b; }
protected:
    A(std::unique_ptr<B> b):m_b(std::move(b)) {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};

class DerivedA : public A
{
public:
    DerivedA() :A(std::make_unique<B>(DerivedB())) {}
    DerivedB& getDerivedB() { return static_cast<DerivedB&>(getB()); }
};
```

Is this solution, which uses a cast, the best?

Comment: Your example wouldn't even compile, since `m_b` in statement `DerivedA():m_b(std::make_unique(DerivedB())) {}` is inaccessible to do it being `private`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` shouldn't be necessary. It seems that your design guarantees that the parent sub object contains a pointer to `DerivedB`, so `static_cast` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated the code so that it would compile!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it inherently a bad design?

Yes, down-casting is ofttimes considered a design smell in C++. It is often a flag indicating that your design is breaking the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).
Instead consider using polymorphism for `B` and `DerivedB` to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of composition, I would use inheritance? I don't get what you mean by using polymorphism, here, could you hint with a code snippet?

Comment: I think that you could do without `getDerivedB()`. `B` will provide interface for the class users of both `B` and `DerivedB`. `DerivedB` will override some of the `B` methods to take into account its specifics. And the user will interact with both `B` and `DerivedB` via the pointer to the base class (`B` in this case). Hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: "`B` will provide interface for the class users of both `B` and `DerivedB`." Do you mean that if, currently, `B` is a `struct` that holds 2 `int` and `DerivedB` adds 3 `floats` to it, I create a `B` interface that provide access to the two `int` and the 3 `float`? Or instead just the 2 `int` and `DerivedB` adds the acces to the 3 `float`? I'm sorry, I don't get it!

Comment: @Michel could you show the concrete example when do you need it? maybe it would be easier to show you that way

Comment: @Michel maybe [this quick and dirty example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yO51GdIQ1m6TVCUS) will make it more clear. `Vector2D` is `B`, `Vector3D` is `DerivedB`, `VectorHolder2D` is `A`, and `VectorHolder3D` is `DerivedA`.

Comment: @Michel also note, how it never needs to access `Vector3D`'s `z`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! It is more clear. The situation I have is very similar to the situation of your example, but my problem is: now the `VectorHolder2D` (could be a BoundingBox2D, for example) gives me a `Vector` when I `getVector`. But we know it is a `Vector2D&`. It is a problem, because if I want to use this vector to build a new BoundingBox2D, it won't do.

Comment: Does not compile yet but I started [another example here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gYNAMNdBW6j7vqlb)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using templates?

I made an example here:
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oMEzjpnsdOmgKTRs

But is it a better way?